# Including External CSS in Laravel 4 without Blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm building a login page that is just h1, two input fields, and a submit button. I really don't need a template for this. Is there a way to include the external css since I can't use {{HTML::whatever}} to include CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use laravel url helpers.

http://laravel.com/docs/helpers#urls

Also you can user HTML::whatever() within `php` tags.

```
<?php

echo HTML::style('assets/stylesheet/main.css');

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. How come <link> doesn't work for including an external sheet?

Answer (score 0):

You can still do it in traditional HTML style inside the view, either with style tags or attaching to an external stylesheet.

Comment: I've tried this using <link>, but it's not including it. What is the path relative to? app folder or public folder?